# SQL Statement // between with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have following query:

```
select s.ScreenID, s.ScreenName, ps.ScheduleDate
from Screens s
left join PerformanceSchedules ps on ps.ScreenID = s.ScreenID
where s.TheatreID = 2 and ((ps.ScheduleDate not between convert(datetime, '2019-08-02 14:00:00.000') and convert(datetime, '2019-08-02 20:00:00.000')) or (ps.ScheduleDate is null))
```

The result of the query is:

```
ScreenID    ScreenName  ScheduleDate
4           Screen 1    2019-08-02 15:00:00.000
5           Screen 2    2019-08-02 15:00:00.000
6           Screen 3    NULL
```

Normally it should only return Screen 3 and not the other two, because the ScheduleDate of the two is in the time span.

The result should be:

```
6   Screen 3    NULL
```

Comment: You have to use  `and ` not  `or`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you really want:

```
select s.ScreenID, s.ScreenName, ps.ScheduleDate
from Screens s left join
     PerformanceSchedules ps
     on ps.ScreenID = s.ScreenID and
        ps.ScheduleDate between convert(datetime, '2019-08-02 14:00:00.000', 121) and convert(datetime, '2019-08-02 20:00:00.000', 121)
where s.TheatreID = 2 and
      ps.ScreenID is null;
```

This will return the screens that have no schedule date between those times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
This also causes all three screens to be returned.

The `ScheduleDate` in the table `PerformanceSchedules` is of type `datetime` and set to `2019-08-02 15:00:00.000`.
Therefore it should be between the two datetimes. But isn´t it, apparently.

Comment: I found the issue! I need to pass a third parameter to convert for converting the date. In my case `121` for `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`